# Given a sequence of expressions, how can I convert them all into functions?

Tags: function-construction

I have a sequence of expressions

```
1, x, x^2, ..., x^5
```

I want to define a sequence of functions out of it, what should I do? Namely I want to define a vector of functions with elements:
$$
f_1 = 1, f_2 = x, ..., f_6 = x^5
$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just keep in mind that `f_1=1,f_2=x,...,f_6=x^5` isn't maathematica syntax (or at least it's not what you want it to be)

Comment: One way to manage lists of functions *and* to create orthogonal bases of them is described in my answer at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19492/how-do-i-solve-n-simultaneous-equations-for-n-variables/19504#19504.  That solution begins `vectors = Function /@ Table[#^k, {k, 0, 6}]`, etc., which directly answers the present question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?:

```
Function[x, Evaluate[x^#]] & /@ Range[0, 5]

(* {Function[x, 1], Function[x, x], Function[x, x^2], 
 Function[x, x^3], Function[x, x^4], Function[x, x^5]} *)
```

Depending on what you'd like to do, it may be better to define and use a single function:

```
Function[x, Evaluate[x^# & /@ Range[0, 5]]]
(*Function[x, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}]*)
%[2]
(*{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}*)
```

Comment: How can I use them later? I need to calculate an orthogonal basis out of this, can I let fun=Function[x, Evaluate[x^#]] & /@ Range[0, 5], and refer to its elements later as fun[i]?

Comment: @TongZhang, see the edit, if that does not help, it might want to rework the question a bit to help understand what it really is that you are looking for.

Comment: +1. B.t.w., `Evaluate` is not really necessary, except the very first function, and for that one only if you want `x^0` to evaluate to 1 at definition time.

Comment: The first line of code is what was looking for.